Webpack 5 (TerserPlugin) - "Import" statement may only appear at the top level
I am unable to minify and building code with Terser in Webpack.
I get the following error while running my production build:
cart-ts.js from Terser plugin
"Import" statement may only appear at the top level [cart-ts.js:33904,0]
    at js_error (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:549:11)
    at TreeWalker.visit (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:11766:13)
    at TreeWalker._visit (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6717:24)
    at AST_Import._walk (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:5129:28)
    at walk_body (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:3876:17)
    at AST_Function.<anonymous> (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:4375:17)
    at <redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6718:21
    at TreeWalker.visit (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:11668:13)
    at TreeWalker._visit (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:6717:24)
    at AST_Function._walk (<redacted>\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:4369:28)

webpack 5.90.3 compiled with 1 error in 77388 ms

Even though I run terser enabling the latest version of ecma and enabiling modules:
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
                ecma: 2023,
                module: true
            }
        })
    ]
}

I suspect it might be due to dynamic imports in my code.
From other answers I've seen solutions using babel-loader and plugins for babel enabling dynamic imports, although I would like to not use babel and babel-loader and keep it as simple as possible.

It seems like the issue is no longer present when using the esbuild minifier.
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            minify: TerserPlugin.esbuildMinify
        }),
    ]
}

